# How can I get it fast with text-field watch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I enter input values ​​as parameters in a text-field. But it works very slowly every time I press a key. How can I speed it up.
html code

```
<v-col cols="3">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="registerSearch">
    </v-text-field>
</v-col>
```

script code

```
 watch: {
    async registerSearch(value){
       if(value){
         if(this.registerSearch.length == 10 || this.registerSearch.length == 11){
           this.customer.TaxNumber=this.registerSearch;
           if(this.registerSearch.length == 11){
             await this.$validator.reset();
             
           }else{
             this.searched=false;
           }
         else{
           this.Search=[]
           this.customer.Company=''
           this.customer.FirstName=''
           this.customer.LastName=''
           this.searched = false;
           this.disableControl=true;
           await this.$validator.reset();
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can try to do do some delay on your search. after user typed in a few character only start to search. Here is the lodash decounce example.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

methods: {
    onChanged: _.debounce(function (event) {
        // search method here...  
    }, 300),
}
```